# Where to find sample audio files of various formats?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am programming to decode different format audio based on ffmpeg, like mp3, aac and so on.
Where can I find different format audio to use as a testset?

Answer (score 1):

See https://samples.ffmpeg.org/ and refer to `allsamples.txt` for the complete list. Some of the samples are related to bug reports and therefore may be weird.